# Output list of names into a sentence with commas and "and"

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to output a list of names from a DE into and email and format with commas and "and"

**Example**
Batman, Super Man and Spider Man

**Code**

```
%%[
var @rows, @rowCount, @numRowsToReturn, @i

set @numRowsToReturn = 0 /* all */
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("191204-NYC-Marketers-Advisor-XREF", @numRowsToReturn,"FullName asc","SC_ContactID", @SC_ContactID)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

]%%

%%[

if @rowCount > 0 then


    for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

        var @First, @AdvisorName

        set @row = row(@rows,@i)
        set @First = Field(@row,"FirstName")
        set @AdvisorName = Field(@row,"Advisor Full Name")



        IF @rowCount == 1 THEN
          outputline(concat(@AdvisorName))
        ELSEIF @rowCount > 1 THEN
        outputline(concat(@AdvisorName, ","))
        ENDIF
        ]%%


        %%[ 



    next @i 

]%%

%%[ else ]%%

No rows found

%%[ endif ]%%
```

**RESULTS** I'm getting is

Batman, Super Man, Spider Man,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `@i` variable and compare with the rowcount to determine whether to use a comma or an 'and'.

```
IF @rowCount == 1 THEN
    outputline(concat(@AdvisorName))
ELSE
    IF @rowCount == @i THEN
        outputline(concat(" and ",@AdvisorName))
    ELSE
        outputline(concat(", ",@AdvisorName))
    ENDIF
ENDIF
```

Comment: Josh you provided me the key to make this work - for that I thank you.